# Simplify addition of 4 sin()s into one term

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to turn $\sin(a)+\sin(b)+\sin(c)+\sin(d)$ into one term, such that there is no addition or subtraction? I've tried by using $$
\sin(a) + \sin(b) =
2 \sin \left(\frac{a+b}{2} \right)\cos \left(\frac{a-b}{2} \right)
$$
but that gets it down to 2 terms. I can see it may not be "simpler" but I'm hoping it will make it easier to differentiate to find roots.

Would it work in a similar way for cos?

Edit: a through d are functions of x and y, for example:

$$a=\sqrt{(1+x)^2+(2+y)^2}, b=\sqrt{(1+x)^2+(2-y)^2}, c=\sqrt{(1-x)^2+(2+y)^2}, d=\sqrt{(1-x)^2+(2-y)^2}
$$

Comment: What are you trying to do with the simplified expression? Differentiate it?

Comment: Yes, to find roots by numerical methods, and differentiate more than once to find maxima/minima.

Comment: Give an example of a function, for which you want to have roots or extrema ?

Comment: what else is given?

Comment: If the derivates get too complicated, you can also use regula falsi (if the functions have only one variable).

Comment: I've added an edit, however the original question still holds; is it possible to have a single term that is equal to the addition of 4 different sin()'s.